# Use Edit function in vf page

Tags: apex, visualforce-component, visualforce

I have to use edit function in a vf page.Please find my apex class and corresponding error showing below.
Apex class:

```
global with sharing class poistionController1 {

     public List<HCP_Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c> my_list {get;set;}
     public HCP_Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c editConRole { get; set; }

     public poistionController1(Apexpages.StandardController Account) {

         my_list= [select Monthly_Call_Attainment_OAPI__c,Name,Account_OAPI__c,HCP_Account_Name_OAPI__c,Active_HCP_DT_OAPI__c,Id,Territory_OAPI__c,Total_Actual_Calls_Month_OAPI__c from HCP_Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c where Depth_Tracker_OAPI__r.Account_OAPI__c = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];

      }

      public void editOneConRole() {
        String editid = getParam('editid');
        editConRole  = [SELECT id, Name FROM
              HCP_Depth_Tracker_oapi__c where id = :editId]; 
              }

}
```

Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: getParam(String) at line 13 column 25

Please find my apex page here.
Apex page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="poistionController1" showHeader="false">

<apex:pageBlock title="HCP DEPTH TRACKER">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!my_list}" var="c">
<apex:commandLink value="Edit" action="{!editOneConRole}" rerender="HCP_Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c">
                                    <apex:param name="editid" value="{!c.Id}"/>
                                </apex:commandLink>
<apex:column headerValue="Name"> {!c.Name} </apex:column>
<apex:column headerValue="Account_oapi__c"> {!c.Account_OAPI__c} </apex:column>
<apex:column headerValue="Monthly_Call_Attainment_OAPI__c"> {!c.Monthly_Call_Attainment_OAPI__c} </apex:column>
<apex:column headerValue="Active_HCP_DT_OAPI__c"> {!c.Active_HCP_DT_OAPI__c} </apex:column>
<apex:column headerValue="Territory_OAPI__c"> {!c.Territory_OAPI__c} </apex:column>
<apex:column headerValue="Id"> {!c.id} </apex:column>
<apex:column headerValue="Total_Actual_Calls_Month_OAPI__c "> {!c.Total_Actual_Calls_Month_OAPI__c } </apex:column>
<apex:column headerValue="HCP_Account_Name_OAPI__c"> {!c.HCP_Account_Name_OAPI__c} </apex:column>

</apex:pageBlockTable>

 </apex:form>
    </apex:pageBlock> 
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

saikat, have u considered using inline edit, here is a link: http://salesforceworld.blogspot.com/2011/06/inline-editing-in-visualforce-page.html

Answer (score 1):

First off the param function needs to be corrected, it is missing **assignedto** value

```
<apex:commandLink value="Edit" action="{!editOneConRole}" rerender="HCP_Depth_Tracker_OAPI__c">
  <apex:param name="editid" value="{!c.Id}" assignedto="{!editid}"/>    
</apex:commandLink>
```

controller:
Add this line:

```
public string editid{get;set;}
```

Remove this line:

```
String editid = getParam('editid');
```

Now the value c.id is passed to the controller through the param function to the controller and assigned to editid variable in the controller.

You can use it in your soql like you do it in your code:

```
editConRole  = [SELECT id, Name FROM
              HCP_Depth_Tracker_oapi__c where id = :editId];
```